# Prove that $\gcd(ab,m)\mid\gcd(a,m)\gcd(b,m)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Prove that if $a,b,m\in\mathbb N\setminus\{0\}$, then
$$\gcd(ab,m)\mid\gcd(a,m)\cdot\gcd(b,m)$$

Comment: What have you tried? If you tell us this then we will be better able to help you. And it helps us feel that we are not just doing your homework for you. For example, have you tried writing down $\gcd(a, m)$ in terms of $a$ and $m$, etc?

Comment: i tried many ways , and its hart to me to explain a have bad english , if you can just to give mne At least right way to start.

Comment: My day job is teaching maths to students who do not speak English as their first language. If you were one of my students I would say "Try to explain. It is good practice."

Comment: i did case 1 as was answerd to me and stucked in case 2 but i think i have idea now tnx .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am frustrated because the OP has run off with an inelegant idea using prime decompositions. So I thought I would at least try to rectify this by giving the following cryptic hint.

**Hint:** $\gcd(a, m)\cdot\gcd(b, m)=abX+mY$ for some $X,Y\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

If you already know ring theory: Show $(A+M)(B+M) \subseteq AB+M$ for ideals $A,B,M$ of a ring. Apply this to $A=(a),B=(b),C=(c)$ in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: You don't even need ring theory, just consider the factors as multisets, although writing $(A + M)(B+M)$ is less direct than starting with $(A+B)M$ imo.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: If you write the factors of a number as multiset (for example the factors of $x = 20$ would be $X = \{2, 2, 5\}$) then $$gcd(ab, m) \mid gcd(a,m)gcd(b,m)$$ becomes $$(A \cup B)\cap M \subseteq (A \cap M) \cup (B \cap M)$$ and it's straightforward...

Answer (score 0):

Assume $d = \gcd(ab,m)$ and then we get $ab = c d $ and $ m = \overline{m} d $ with $\gcd(c,\overline{m}) = 1 $.

Furthermore let $d_{a} = \gcd(a,m) $ and $d_{b} = \gcd(b,m)$,So you want to prove $d | d_{a}d_{b}$,Please Try it again.